# Meaning of the phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning, quotes

We do not count a man's years until he has nothing else to count

Comment: Perhaps it refers to the order in which things that can be counted are counted. The man's achievements, children, money, etc. then right at the end, his age. The ordering may imply the low significance the phrase assigns to age. That is, that one is never/seldom too young or too old; everything else matters more.

Comment: I think this may imply that age does not matter in comparison to other things as Lawrence says, achievements, children, money, etc.  That you shouldn't judge people simply by their age.  I may have got the wrong idea, **could you share the context you found this phrase?**

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from Ralph Waldo Emerson's January 1862 [article](https://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/issues/1862jan/emerson.htm) in The Atlantic Monthly titled "Old Age". The reference in that article to [Tithonus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonus)

> Eos asked Zeus to make Tithonus immortal, she forgot to ask that he be
>   granted eternal youth. Tithonus indeed lived forever, but when
>   loathsome old age pressed full upon him, and he could not move nor
>   lift his limbs, this seemed to her in her heart the best counsel: she
>   laid him in a room and put to the shining doors. There he babbles
>   endlessly, and no more has strength at all, such as once he had in his
>   supple limbs.

makes it clear that the quote refers to the loss of faculties that come with old age. All that is left is the count of years (i.e. age).